# Entity framework working with multiple connection strings vb.net

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, ado.net, ado.net-entity-data-model

I am using entity framework and have multiple databases to work with. I would like different users to connect to different databases. In my connection string in web.config, it goes like this.

```
 <add name="ADBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://EF_DAL;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;data source=pc:15/xe;password=l;user id=l&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
 <add name="BDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://EF_DAL;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;data source=pc:15/xe;password=2;user id=2&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

In my auto generated file from model1.context.vb, the following is generated

```
Partial Public Class DBEntities
    Inherits DbContext

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New("name=DBEntities")
    End Sub
```

what i would like to do is to be able to have the users connect to different database. I figured out being a partial class. I tried to create another class like this

```
Partial Public Class DALEntities
    Inherits DBEntities

    Private Sub New(nameOfConnectionString As String)
        MyBase.New(nameOfConnectionString)
    End Sub
End Class
```

However of course it will not work becos DBEntities does not have a New() which takes in arguments. Is there a way to overcome this by editing settings in the autogeneration process or to overcome this problem programatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply create a class that inherits directly from DbContext instead of the auto-generated class.

This assumes that the database schemas referenced by each connection string are the same.  If they are not, there would be a bit more work to do as far as the model is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that declaring this method in a seperate class did the trick for me

Partial Public Class DBEntities

```
Private Sub New(nameOfConnectionString As String)
    MyBase.New(nameOfConnectionString)
End Sub
```

End Class